# How to setup Detail Accessory Type in Custom Cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, accessorytype

I have custom cell class for each cell I have on my table. I added detail accessory type to each cell. I want the user to click on the detail accessory type (the blue circle with i in it) and a pop up should show more information about that specific cell. I have googled around and have not found a solution for detail accessory type.

[image]

Following is the custom class for my first cell.

```
class SocialTableCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var social:UILabel?  
@IBOutlet weak var toggle:UISwitch?

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
}
override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
}
}
```

Any Help will be highly appreciated. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `UITableViewDelegate` protocol has a method `tableView:accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:` that is being called when a user tapped on the accessory button in one of the cells. So you have to implement that method in your TableViewController:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
   // show the alert here
}
```

Also you have to make sure that you set the `UITableView.delegate` to the ViewController that implements that method.

Comment: Swift 5.1 uses `IndexPath` instead of `NSIndexPath`.